# Cannot save result to List<Long> after manipulating two streams

Tags: java, lambda, collections

I am filtering through two streams and doing a division in the middle, but at the end I cannot collect my result into a List. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is the code I have

```
List<Long> average_population = total_population.stream() 
    .flatMapToLong( a-> number_of_cities.stream().mapToLong( b-> b/a ))
    .collect(null, Collectors.toList() );   <- error
```

Here is the error I get on the last line.

> The method collect(Supplier, ObjLongConsumer, BiConsumer) in the type LongStream is not applicable for the arguments (null, Collector>)
>       Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collector> to ObjLongConsumer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`LongStream.collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.ObjLongConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) requires 3 parameters.
You're probably looking for this:

```
List<Long> average_population =
  total_population.stream()
    .flatMapToLong(a -> number_of_cities.stream().mapToLong(b -> b / a))
    .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
```

But actually, sticking to `Long` doesn't bring you much benefit,
it will be simpler to write using `flatMap`,
which will allow you to use a simpler `collect` too:

```
List<Long> average_population =
  total_population.stream()
    .flatMap(a -> number_of_cities.stream().map(b -> b / a))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to collect the results in a `List<Long>` you need to box the values. The `flatMapToLong` gives a `LongStream` which gives primitive `long`, not boxed `Long`. You can make boxed objects from the long stream with the .boxed() operator.

```
LongStream.of(1l, 2l, 3l).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So I guess it would become:

```
List<Long> average_population = total_population.stream()
      .flatMapToLong(a -> number_of_cities.stream().mapToLong(b -> b / a))
      .boxed()
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```